# ASP.NET Core 1 Dependency Injection: Implementation type always null

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I have the following inside my `ConfigureServices` method in the `Startup` class.
I am adding a singleton instance of `ToastNotification` which is an implementation of `IToastNotification`.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddInstance<IToastNotification>(new ToastNotification()
         {
         });
}
```

The problem is that when I watch the value of services while debugging at the end of this method, the implementation type of the `IToastNotification` service is `null`. Therefore, when I try to get the Toastnotification instance from the services collection in the controllers, it is always null.

This is how I am getting the `Toastnotification` using dependency injection

```
[FromServices]
private IToastNotification ToastNotification { get; set; }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use property injection, it has been removed and won't work in the future versions: https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/115.

Instead, consider using constructor dependency injection.

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said. I guess I need to keep a close eye on all the breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

Using constructor dependency injection, you can do thing like that:

```
// Register your service.
services.AddInstance<IToastNotification>(new ToastNotification());
```

And in your Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IToastNotification _toastNotification;

    public HomeController(IToastNotification toastNotification)
    {
        _toastNotification = toastNotification;
    }

    ...
}
```